# Google tag manager event not showing Facebook meta data information

Tags: laravel, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel, google-tag-manager-server-side

Facebook pixel not showing metadata information on my custom website(php Laravel).
I already created an event from Google Tag Manager and I want to collect information via
that event.

here is my code example below:

```
 <button id="exampleButton" type="submit">Buy Now</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById('exampleButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        gtag("event", "AddToCart", {
        'event_category': 'Engagement',
        'event_label': 'event label',
     });
 });
</script>
```